# How to make sed read its script from a file?

Tags: unix, sed

Recently I came across following grep command:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -Ff grep.txt input.txt > output.txt
```

which as per my understanding means that from input.txt, grep the matter contained in grep.txt and output it to output.txt.

I want to do something similar for sed i.e. I want to keep the sed commands in a separate file (say sed.txt) and want to apply them on input file (say input.txt) and create a output file (say output.txt).

I tried following:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/sed -f sed.txt input.txt > output.txt
```

It does not work and I get the following error:

```
sed: command garbled
```

The contents of files mentioned above are as below:

sed.txt

```
sed s/234/acn/ input.txt
sed s/78gt/hit/ input.txt
```

input.txt

```
234GH
5234BTW
89er
678tfg
234
234YT
tfg456
wert
78gt
gh23444
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your `sed.txt` should only contain `sed` commands: No prefixing with `sed` or suffixing with an input file. In your case it should probably be:

```
# sed.txt
s/234/acn/
s/78gt/hit/
```

When ran on your input:

```
$ /usr/xpg4/bin/sed -f sed.txt input.txt
```

```
acnGH
5acnBTW
89er
678tfg
acn
acnYT
tfg456
wert
hit
ghacn44
```

Answer (score 22):

Rather than keeping the sed commands in a separate text file, you may want to try creating a sed script. The file below can run directly on your data files:

./myscript.sed inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt

```
#!/bin/sed -f
s/234/acn/
s/78gt/hit/
```